# Retrieve custom variable

Tags: variables

I created a simple plugin for changing the body background colour. But I cannot retrieve the variable that the colour is stored.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My Plugin
Version: 1.0
License: GPL2
*/
/** Step 2 (from text above). */
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu' );
add_action('wp_head','hook_css');
// $opt_val = $opt_name = $data_field_name = null;

/** Step 1. */
function my_plugin_menu() {
add_management_page( 'My Plugin Options', 'My Plugin', 'manage_options',      'my-unique-identifier', 'my_plugin_options' );
}
/*Step 3. */
function my_plugin_options($opt_val) {
global $opt_val, $opt_name;

//must check that the user has the required capability
if (!current_user_can('manage_options'))
{
  wp_die( __('You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.')   );
}

// variables for the field and option names
$opt_name = 'mt_favorite_color';
$hidden_field_name = 'mt_submit_hidden';
$data_field_name = 'mt_favorite_color';

// Read in existing option value from database
$opt_val = get_option( $opt_name );

// See if the user has posted us some information
// If they did, this hidden field will be set to 'Y'
if( isset($_POST[ $hidden_field_name ]) && $_POST[ $hidden_field_name ] == 'Y' ) {
    // Read their posted value
    $opt_val = $_POST[ $data_field_name ];

    // Save the posted value in the database
    update_option( $opt_name, $opt_val );

    // Put a "settings saved" message on the screen

 ?>
 <div class="updated"><p><strong><?php _e('Settings saved.', 'menu-test' );   ?></strong></p></div>
 <?php

}

// Now display the settings editing screen

echo '<div class="wrap">';

// header

echo "<h2>" . __( 'Menu Test Plugin Settings', 'menu-test' ) . "</h2>";

// settings form

?>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $hidden_field_name; ?>" value="Y">

<p><?php _e("Favorite Color:", 'menu-test' ); ?>
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $data_field_name; ?>" value="<?php echo     $opt_val; ?>" size="20">
</p><hr />

<p class="submit">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php    esc_attr_e('Save Changes') ?>" />
</p>

</form>
</div>

<?php;
}
function hook_css() {
global $opt_val;
echo "style> body { background-color :" . $opt_val ."!important; }  </style>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `$opt_val` global variable is being set only when the `my_plugin_options` function is called. And that function is being called only in case user is viewing the My Plugin Options screen.

You'll have to call `get_option( 'mt_favorite_color' );` inside the `hook_css` function. (Please note that the `hook_css` function is not being prefixed. All custom functions, global variables, options etc really shold be prefixed).

Further, the code you shared is not sanitisating values on user input, nor escaping theme on the output. Make sure to read [Validating Sanitizing and Escaping User Data part of the codex.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data) and use `sanitize_text_field` before saving the value to the database, and `esc_attr` when outputting the value in order to make the plugin more secure.